# Loading jquery-mobile page in android

Tags: android, jquery-mobile

How can i load jquery-mobile web page in my android application and also where i need to put my jquery-mobile html file in my android application folder so can i access it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the html file in assets folder of your application and then use webview to load the same.

```
 WebView wv= (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv);
 wv.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
 WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings();
 webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/myfile.html");
```

Comment: @ButaniVijay i just did. put your html file in your assests folder and then use webview to loadurl with the path of the.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can wrap your HTML pages inside the Android Application.

You can add your files into your `assets` folder and can show them inside the Android `WebView`. Read more about [Android WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) and here an [example](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-webview-example/). With WebView you gonna have to do something as below.

I assume `wv` is the WebView ID used in our layout xml

```
WebView wv= (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv);
wv.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/myfile.html");
```

If you wanna manipulate the HTML String then you may do something as below

```
InputStream is = getAssets().open("myfile.html");
int size = is.available();

byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
is.read(buffer);
is.close();

String str = new String(buffer);
str = str.replace("old string", "new string");
```

Going further, there is a wonderful Java library that can do so much on HTML String (parsing, querying etc etc). [Check out jSoup](http://jsoup.org/).

If you are interested in Hybrid apps (Web and Native) then check out [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/), [Appcelerator](http://www.appcelerator.com/)

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks  @Mayu Mayooresan

Answer (score 1):

Try [phonegap](http://phonegap.com/) to deploy your html5 application into the mobile.

The `/www` folder contains a sample website.

You can try fiddling with it & see how they expose the mobile api into javascript. There is lots of help regarding that on their website.

You can either add the jquery mobile file along with the website or load it dynamically from their cdn. I would however prefer publishing it along with the application, but then it also means regular updating of the app in future.